Please enable syntax highlighting for RE.SE
Based on How about finally enabling syntax highlighting for RE.SE?, I would like to request that syntax highlighting be activated for our site. (See that post for reasoning and examples.)
We are not a high traffic site and consequently neither is our meta site, but I hope that the existing votes suffice to get this rolling. Thanks.

Syntax highlighting is now enabled on your site. Note that there is no default language currently selected, so site moderators will need to select one on a per-tag basis.
Mods: Not a super hard process. Go to any tag's page, click "Learn more..." and you should see the options there.



And the controls...



Images from Quantum Computing, but they should apply equally well here.

Thanks so much. I will see to it and discuss with the other mods for those where the decision about the default language is debatable.
